# Vue javascript application not calling app.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Am just starting with Vue.js and ui development, and I am trying to make a very simple vue.js call. However, when I am launching my html page using liveserver on Visual Studio Code no JavaScript function is getting called from app.js. I cant figure out what is wrong with the code.

Can someone please advise?
Vue included in HTML-

```
 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Vue Basics</title>
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jost:wght@400;700&display=swap"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next" defer></script>
<script src="app.js" defer></script>
```

app.js code -

```
function getRandomValue(min, max){
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;}
const app = Vue.createApp({

data(){
    return{
        playerHealth:100,
        monsterHealth:100
    };

},
methods:{
    attackMonster(){
        console.log('attack called')
       const attackValue = getRandomValue(5,12);
       this.monsterHealth = this.monsterHealth - attackValue;
       this.attackPlayer()
    },

    attackPlayer(){
        console.log('attack Player called')
        const attackValue =  getRandomValue(8,15);
        this.playerHealth = this.playerHealth - attackValue;
     }
}
 });
```

Comment: I can see you've defined methods, but I can't see you calling any of them. Try doing something on the `created()` [hook](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount your app to a `<div>` tag, for example:

In your html:

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

In `app.js`:

```js
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

Here is the detailed explanation from Vue.js documentation:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/instance.html#creating-an-application-instance

Answer (score 0):

You have defined methods `attackMonster` and `attackPlayer` but you didn't call them. You can use `created()` to call them or you can also use `mounted()` (if you need to access DOM).

```js
  created () {
    this.attackMonster();
  }
```

Also you need to mount Vue app to HTML.

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
/** the rest of your vue app */
  
/** the rest of your vue app */

  created () {
    this.attackMonster();
  }
})

const vm = app.mount('#app');
```

html

```html
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <p>playerHealth: {{ playerHealth }}</p>
      <p>monsterHealth: {{ monsterHealth }}</p>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the path in your script tag

```
<script src="/path/to/app.js" defer></script>
```